# Access Gmail via IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy, gmail, webmail

I work at various sites, and it's not always possible to access my Gmail account due to various firewall restrictions.

However I can access my server at home (which has a static ip). My server runs Windows 2008 R2 (x64). I was wondering if it was possible to get my server to reflect my Gmail account?

So I would do this

http://myserverip/gmail

And my server would present the Gmail page, however my server would be the one accessing Google.

If this is possible, would you please mind detailing how?

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run squid (web proxy) on your server, with `http_access allow` acl's for the external IP's of your work-sites (you wouldn't want everyone on the internet to access it), then simply route your browser through your home IP as its proxy, this way you can connect to any site on the internet bypassing all filtering. (Assuming you can connect to your home IP on one of these ports 80/8080/443/3128 etc.. squid will listen on whatever port you assign it)

Its free, and there is a windows version: http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/

Note: I haven't tested on windows 2008 or 64bit, but it does work on windows 2003/XP.

Failing that, you could setup a webserver that reflects the gmail site.. not sure if that would work though.. I bet you get IIS7 for free with 2008, so you could try something like this: http://www.iisproxy.net/download.html

You could also achieve it with SSH tunnelling.. There is a free OpenSSH windows version here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/files/OpenSSH%20for%20Windows%20-%20Release/

Read up here for a quick overview of SSH tunnelling: http://www.buzzsurf.com/surfatwork/

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply. I had previously looked at squid, however I wanted to do this via IIS. The IISProxy looks very interesting. I will try that this evening, thank you for your help.

Comment: I couldn't get IISProxy to work under IIS7 I think it's a bit outdated. I'll have to try squib next.